# My kg and lbs conversion is always off by significant amount

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to store all my measurements in metric units, but want users to be able to view or submit in metric or imperial. I'm using very exact conversions, and I am absolutely sure I'm using the right numbers. In spite of this, every time I enter 180 pounds, convert to kg or MySQL storage, and convert it back to lbs, I am getting 180.77905484 back as a result. Here is my code.

Before entering into database as kg

```
$weight = $weight * 0.45359237;
```

After retrieving from database as kg

```
$kg_conv = 2.20462262;
echo $progress->weight * $kg_conv;
```

I would understand if it was off by a hundredth of a pound, or off by several pounds, but why would it only be off by 0.77 pounds?

Comment: What kind of column are you using to store the converted value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are (somewhere) rounding your converted kilogram value.

`180 * 0.45359237` is `81.6466266`, that's fine.

`81.6465266 * 2.20462262` is `179.99999985`, and that's also fine. This is within the realm of accuracy loss due to floating point. The numbers and the math are both fine.

However, you don't have those numbers. You cannot. Your value, `180.77905484`, is the result of  a kilogram input of exactly `82`. `82 * 2.20462262` is the `180.77905484` you're getting.

So, somewhere, either before writing to or after reading from the database, you are rounding your converted-to-kilograms value of `180 * 0.45359237` and going from `81.6466266` to `82`.